# Minimize multiple Div with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I'm trying to add an animation on the width property for my div .panels. Ive tried it in css with *transition-property,* and with *.animate()*, but it doesnt work.
and I noticed that calc() is not working with jQuery animate...

The third panel should always have the subtraction of the other two width, so it can float on the right.

```
ex. width: 'calc(100% - ' + (panelWidth1 + panelWidth2) + 'px)'
```

So any suggestion to make it work ?
Thanks!

**HMTL**

```
<div class="actions">
  <button id="MinPanel1">Minimize Panel 1</button>
  <button id="MinPanel2">Minimize Panel 2</button>
</div>

<div class="panels">
  <div class="panel1"></div>
  <div class="panel2"></div>
  <div class="panel3"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#MinPanel1').click(function() {
        var toggleWidth = $(".panel1").width() == 225 ? "57px" : "225px";
        $('.panel1').css({
            width: toggleWidth
        });
        adjustPanel();
    });

    $('#MinPanel2').click(function() {
        var toggleWidth = $(".panel2").width() == 330 ? "66px" : "330px";
        $('.panel2').css({
            width: toggleWidth
        });
        adjustPanel();
    });


    adjustPanel = function() {
        var panelWidth1 = $('.panel1').width();
        var panelWidth2 = $('.panel2').width();
        var panelWidthTotal = panelWidth1 + panelWidth2;

        $('.panel3').css({
            width: '-webkit-calc(100% - ' + panelWidthTotal + 'px)',
            width: '-moz-calc(100% - ' + panelWidthTotal + 'px)',
            width: 'calc(100% - ' + panelWidthTotal + 'px)'
        });
    }

});
```

**CSS**

```
[...]

.panel1, .panel2, .panel3{
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    /*-moz-transition-property: width;
    -o-transition-property: width;
    -webkit-transition-property: width;
    transition-property: width;
    -moz-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-duration: 300ms;*/
}

[...]
```

**DEMO : [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/scutz8vv/)**

**EDITED DEMO RESULT: [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mdp1ov2w/2/)**

Comment: you know that in you fiddle you are not using jquery?

Comment: He does have jquery, but as an external resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#MinPanel1').click(function() {
        var toggleWidth = $(".panel1").width() == 225 ? "57px" : "225px";
        $('.panel1').animate({
            width: toggleWidth
        },function(){
            adjustPanel($('.panel1').width(), $('.panel2').width())
        });
    });

    $('#MinPanel2').click(function() {
        var toggleWidth = $(".panel2").width() == 330 ? "66px" : "330px";
        $('.panel2').animate({
            width: toggleWidth
        },function(){
            adjustPanel($('.panel1').width(), $('.panel2').width())
        });
    });


    adjustPanel = function(pan1, pan2) {
    console.log($('.panels').width(), pan1, pan2);
        var panelWidthTotal = $('.panels').width() - (pan1 + pan2) + 'px';

        $('.panel3').animate({
            width: panelWidthTotal
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working code. It works with css transition, and just has the js a bit rewritten because the code needs the final width of the divs and not the one it would grab while the animation lasts.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    $('#MinPanel1').click(function() {
        var toggleWidth = $(".panel1").width() == 225 ? "57px" : "225px";
        var toggleWidth1=toggleWidth;
        $('.panel1').css({
            width: toggleWidth
        });
        adjustPanel();
    });
    
    $('#MinPanel2').click(function() {
        var toggleWidth = $(".panel2").width() == 330 ? "66px" : "330px";
        var toggleWidth2=toggleWidth;
        $('.panel2').css({
            width: toggleWidth
        });
        adjustPanel();
    });
    
    
    adjustPanel = function() {
        var panelWidth1 = toggleWidth1;
        var panelWidth2 = toggleWidth2;
        var panelWidthTotal = panelWidth1 + panelWidth2;
        
        $('.panel3').css({
            width: '-webkit-calc(100% - ' + panelWidthTotal + 'px)',
            width: '-moz-calc(100% - ' + panelWidthTotal + 'px)',
            width: 'calc(100% - ' + panelWidthTotal + 'px)'
        });
    }
    
});
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.actions{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
}

.actions button{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.panels{
    height: 100%;
}
.panel1, .panel2, .panel3{
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    /*-moz-transition-property: width;
    -o-transition-property: width;
    -webkit-transition-property: width;
    transition-property: width;
    -moz-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-duration: 300ms;*/
}

.panel1{
    width: 225px;
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 2s;

}

.panel2{
    width: 330px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 2s;
}

.panel3{
    width: calc(100% - 555px);
    background-color: darkgreen;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="actions">
  <button id="MinPanel1">Minimize Panel 1</button>
  <button id="MinPanel2">Minimize Panel 2</button>
</div>

<div class="panels">
  <div class="panel1"></div>
  <div class="panel2"></div>
  <div class="panel3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I realize that this doesn't work fully, edit coming in a sec